# ¿Como hacer AUTO_INCREMENT sobre una llave compuesta que solo afecte a una llave?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo una tabla de 'Grupo' que maneja los grupos que se abren de materias. La llave de esta tabla es el numero de grupo + código de materia

Si tengo:

---

Materia          No_Grupo
TC2016         1
TC2016         2
TC2016         3

---

El AUTO_INCREMENT funciona bien pero quiero que cuando agregue otro código de materia, el AUTO_INCREMENT vaya sobre otra cuenta de esa materia. Lo que hace en cambio es:

---

MA1056         4

---

¿Como hacer para que vuelva a empezar de 1 teniendo otro código de materia?

Answer (score 2):

Una opción para solventar el problema puede ser por medio de una **secuencia**.

Actualmente, a diferencia de otros productos, MySQL no tiene soporte nativo para esta funcionalidad, sin embargo, una manera básica de implementarla es por medio de disparadores (triggers), funcionaes, entre otras funcionalidades.

Ejemplo:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sequences`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sequences` (
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `val` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `nextgroup`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `nextgroup` (`p_sequence_name` VARCHAR(6))
    -> RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
    -> READS SQL DATA
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `sequences` (`name`, `val`)
    ->   VALUES (`p_sequence_name`, LAST_INSERT_ID(1))
    ->     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `val` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`val` + 1);
    ->   RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `materia_grupo`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materia_grupo` (
    ->   `cod_materia` VARCHAR(6), 
    ->   `no_grupo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`cod_materia`, `no_grupo`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_materia_grupo_bi`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_materia_grupo_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `materia_grupo`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET NEW.`no_grupo` := IF(NEW.`no_grupo` = 0,
    ->                            `nextgroup`(NEW.`cod_materia`),
    ->                            NEW.`no_grupo`);
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `materia_grupo`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('TC2016');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('TC2016');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('MA1056');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('TC2016');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('TC2016');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `materia_grupo` (`cod_materia`)
    -> VALUES ('MA1056');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `cod_materia`,
    ->   `no_grupo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `materia_grupo`;
+-------------+----------+
| cod_materia | no_grupo |
+-------------+----------+
| MA1056      |        1 |
| MA1056      |        2 |
| TC2016      |        1 |
| TC2016      |        2 |
| TC2016      |        3 |
| TC2016      |        4 |
+-------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `val`
    -> FROM
    ->   `sequences`;
+--------+-----+
| name   | val |
+--------+-----+
| MA1056 |   2 |
| TC2016 |   4 |
+--------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando el motor MyISAM, sí puedes definir el autoincremento de una columna dado que sea parte de una llave compuesta, en cuyo caso el prefijo de la llave compuesta determina el autoincremento: [example auto increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html#idm140114953377472). Definirías tu tabla como:

```
CREATE TABLE materia_grupo (
    materia CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    grupo MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY (materia,grupo)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

En InnoDB no se puede hacer esta definición y tienes que recurir a triggers como el que señala @wchiquito.